# Powershell script to execute command line program that expects user input

Tags: powershell, shell

I have to do a Powershell script that allows me to create a NocoDB instance on my Pc.
The script needs to execute command
`npx create-nocodb-app`
which requires user to insert some inputs.

What i want to complete is something similar:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZdT4.png)
Note that the first input is a selection from a list (i have to press three times arrow down and after press Enter).
It's possibile to do something similar?